# Streaming Face Recognition Video and Meta-data in Flask

Tags: python, flask, video-streaming

The task is to recognize faces in a video stream and to draw bounding boxes on the video frames and to show the person's name. Need to stream video frames and metadata (names) from the API. The API makes a call to a GPU intensive machine learning subroutine which can be made to return a frame and name pair in a Python tuple. To reduce, computation we tried to make a single function call per frame processed. tuple contains a bytes type frame and a string type name.

### How to show stream video frames and metadata (names) from the API?

```
 def get_frame():
   recog = VideoFaceRecog(target="/video/m.mp4")
while True:
   (ret, frame) = recog.cap.read()

  if not ret:
    print('end of the video file...')
    break

  cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))
  frame, names, bounding_boxes = recog.frame_recog(frame)

  camera_frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1].tobytes()

  yield (b'--frame\r\n'
       b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + camera_frame + b'\r\n')
@app.route('/camera_feed', methods=['GET'])
def video_feed():
   return Response(stream_with_context((get_frame())), 
                        mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

Answer (score 0):

recog = VideoFaceRecog()

```
def get_frame(recog):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        (ret, frame) = cap.read()

        if not ret:
            print('end of the video file...')
            break
        frame, names, bounding_boxes = recog.frame_recog(frame)
        recog.add_name(names) 
        camera_frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1].tobytes()
        yield ((b'--frame\r\n'
            b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + camera_frame + b'\r\n'))
```

Call meta-data in a different endpoint.